# Query with subquery returns null

Tags: c#, t-sql

I Have a query with returns no results despite there are still plenty of rows to process.

```
SELECT O.[OrderLineId]
, O.[Article]
, O.[ArticleDescription]
, O.[QtyOrdered]
, O.[QtyDelivered]
, O.[BoxId]
, O.[Status]
, O.[Picker]
, O.[PickLocation]
, O.[Sorting]
, O.[DateCreated]
, O.[DateModified]
FROM [dbo].[PickBatch] P 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Boxes] B ON P.PickBatchId = B.PickBatchId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrderLines] O ON B.BoxId = O.BoxId
WHERE P.PickBatchId = @PickBatchId 
AND (O.[Status] = @Status)
AND (O.[PickLocation] = (SELECT TOP(1) O.[PickLocation] 
                        FROM [dbo].[PickBatch] P 
                      INNER JOIN [dbo].[Boxes] B ON P.PickBatchId = B.PickBatchId
                      INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrderLines] O ON B.BoxId = O.BoxId
                      WHERE P.PickBatchId = @PickBatchId 
                      AND O.[Status] = @Status      
                      ORDER BY O.Sorting))
```

It looks like the subquery returns a result and meanwhile the status is changed so that the main query returns no results. Is this possible? Or do I make another mistake?

When the query returns no results the users is prompted that everything is picked and he can start a new batch. When he want's to start a new batch there a check if he hasn't an open batch. This fires few queries and this query. Then the query returns a result. So basically query is fired no results, sec. later same query returns results.

Comment: For clarification, could you provide example data and expected results of your query ?

Comment: perhaps you need to move your selects around you seem to be after stuff from O with checks on B and P..

Comment: Please post a data set and the expected result set

Comment: Please change your aliases in subquery

Answer (score 0):

I want to suppose your query is exact but you can't use the same alias in main query and sub query. Aliases are used to differentiate the same table. So in your subquery:

- instead of `P` use `P2`
- instead of `B` use `B2`
- instead of `O` use `O2`

So. If your query doens't work please post a data set and expected result set

Comment: Using the different aliases didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe **primary keys** for this tables. I think problem with sub query always return a row but don't matched with main query values.